# CSS Grid: Auto-fit behaving like Auto-fill when using grid-column-start/end

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

I'm running into some confusion when it comes to CSS Grid. I have the grid-template-columns set to auto-fit and that works perfectly fine. Except as soon as I set column-start/end on div5, I start getting auto-fill behavior instead where multiple blank cells are being created. It seems like the max 1fr of my minmax function isn't doing it's job.

Am I missing something obvious here?

```
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}

#div5 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: -1;
}
```

Images below show increasing/decreasing window size that shows auto-fill behavior.

[image: Larger Window]

[image: Smaller Window]

**Added Code Snippet as per request** You have to make sure you run it in full screen and increase the screen size horizontally to see the issue.

```css
/* Div Styles */
#div1 { background: yellow     }
#div2 { background: dodgerblue }
#div3 { background: tomato     }
#div4 { background: limegreen  }
#div5 { background: yellow     }


/* Body Style */
body { margin: 0; }


/* Grid Settings */
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, 1fr);
}

#div5 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="div1">Div 1</div>
  <div id="div2">Div 2</div>
  <div id="div3">Div 3</div>
  <div id="div4">Div 4</div>
  <div id="div5">Div 5</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: could you give more code or provide the snippet?

Comment: @Bryner do you want the first 4 items always to fill the first row and the last item always to fill the second row... like this?https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/mKEqyo

Comment: @Danield Yes! That's perfect! So I guess the repeat is what's causing the issue? I'm trying to understand why it would though. My guess is that the repeat is also affecting div5 and because div5 is always taking up the whole screen, the repeat thinks there's more items available and keeps auto-fitting div5 to new columns or something? I don't know.. I'm confused but yes, your solution is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the first 4 items always to fill the first row and the last item always to fill the second row.

This means that you want a 4-column grid with the final item spanning all 4 columns.

```
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

#div5 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: -1;
}
```

```css
/* Div Styles */
#div1 { background: yellow     }
#div2 { background: dodgerblue }
#div3 { background: tomato     }
#div4 { background: limegreen  }
#div5 { background: aqua     }


/* Body Style */
body { margin: 0; }


/* Grid Settings */
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, 1fr);
}

#div5 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: -1;
}
```

```html
  <div id="div1">Div 1</div>
  <div id="div2">Div 2</div>
  <div id="div3">Div 3</div>
  <div id="div4">Div 4</div>
  <div id="div5">Div 5</div>
```

The problem with the original code:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
```

is that it uses `auto-fit` which is meant for responsive layout grids where the amount of columns isn't fixed but rather the grid makes new columns based on the grid content and layout method.

That obviously isn't what you need in your case.